# Can I create a (new) lookup table in Power Pivot by querying other tables in my data model?

Tags: dax, powerpivot, lookup-tables, datamodel

**Context:**
I am creating a dashboard in Excel based on the data model I am building in Power Pivot. The source data in the data model is based on various other excel tables I am regularly receiving and copy-pasting into my workbook (their incoming structure is out of my control). My goal is to perform all data processing within Power Pivot/DAX rather than manipulating the data in the worksheets before loading into the model.

**Problem:**
In my model, I have a table (tabCases) which includes status updates on all cases from a management system. This table has a column named case-ID (not unique). I need to create a lookup-table with unique case-id's where I can create new columns with various KPIs for each case.

**How can I do this in Power Pivot?**

I found two suggestions in [this article](https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/03/creating-dynamic-lookup-tables-with-unique-values-using-power-query-instead-of-a-database/) but none of them work for me (opt. 1 because it requires a manual creation of the unique ID list and opt. 2 because I don't have a database access).

In my mind there should be something really simple I could do, such as i.e.:

1. Add new table to data model
2. Set first column to be equal to DISTINCT(tabCases[caseID])

**Is there such a way?**

[image: Illustration of what I have and need]

Answer (score 0):

A Linkback Table might help you. Please see the link below:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/linkback-tables-in-powerpivot-for-excel-2013/

Thanks